# ssh connection not working in php

Tags: php, linux, ssh

Using putty I can able to connect. But using PHP I can't. I don't know ,why it is happening? I installed and enabled the extension ssh2 in PHP.

I used the following Code:-

```
$ssh2 = ssh2_connect('myhost');
if (false === $ssh2) {
 die('connection failed');
}
$auth = @ssh2_auth_password($ssh, "hostusername", "hostpassword");
if (false === $auth) {
  die('authentication failed');
}
echo ssh2_exec($ssh2,'pwd');
```

But this will the following error:
 **Warning: ssh2_exec(): Connection not authenticated**

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Your SSH authentication is for $ssh not for $ssh2. (line 5)

Answer (score 0):

You have type for $ssh, not $ssh2 Line 5.

Your code must be

```
$ssh2 = ssh2_connect('myhost');
if (false === $ssh2) {
 die('connection failed');
}
$auth = @ssh2_auth_password($ssh2, "hostusername", "hostpassword");
if (false === $auth) {
  die('authentication failed');
}
echo ssh2_exec($ssh2,'pwd');
```